# How to give permission on the folder in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a problem with images in the text when you press the texts with images of the images do not show a 302 error.
  expecionar the location the element appears in the following URL / Account / Login? ReturnUrl =% 2fArquivos% 2Fimages% 2fe2510970-47c3-215E-A460-4b8a06ba3484.jpg
  I tried the following setting but still did not show the images.

```
<location path="~/WikiSanitas/Arquivos/Imagens"  allowOverride="false">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```